# Ajax and HTML Snapshot redirect

Tags: html, ajax

I am having a simple html page that loads some dynamic content using HTML dom with script tags. The link to the page is simple like this. www.mysite.com/page1.html.

Now, In order for me to set this page crawlable I have to make sure that I have static content on the url www.mysite.com/page1.html?_escaped_fragment_=

I am very confused how to achieve this. Do I have to create a html file with name "page1.html?_escaped_fragment_=" or do I have handle parameters? how can I make sure that if www.mysite.com/page1.html?_escaped_fragment_= is typed in the address bar, I will go to the static html page I am going to create?

Thanks in advance.

Ganesh.

Comment: The [hashbang hack is horrible](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) and is obsoleted by [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). I recommend not using it instead of trying to deal with Google's `_escaped_fragment_` nonsense.

Comment: I am sorry, you are putting too much in to my plate :-) . I am unable to understand simple things as I am not a web developer. Could you please explain me what you are suggesting. All I want is google to index the dynamic content in my page. I have no knowlege about redirecting parameterized html. Please bear with me to explain in detail.